# How to execute multiple statements in multiple terminals? (Linux, Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation, ros

I'm trying to write a script that opens 3 terminal windows and runs a couple of statements in those windows. But it's not working. I've tried using the && operator as well as " " but I can't get it to work. I've also tried it with the statements on the same line as well as below each other. The error I'm receiving is that the cd child process failed to execute stating that there is no such Directory. But the directory ~/Projects/catkin_ws is correct.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ROS opstarten
gnome-terminal -e cd ~/Projects/catkin_ws source devel/setup.bash roscore

# gazebo opstarten
gnome-terminal -e cd ~/Projects/catkin_ws 
source devel/setup.bash
roslaunch cvg_sim_gazebo Qr_Chessboard.launch

# programma opstarten
gnome-terminal -e cd ~/Projects/catkin_ws
source devel/setup.bash
/usr/bin/python /home/user/Projects/catkin_ws/src/drone7_project/src/drone_program.py
```

Comment: Also, try to execute `cd ~/Projects/catkin_ws` in the terminal and check whether it is working. I hope you are assuming your `$HOME` location as `~`.

Comment: Yeah. The statements all work separately. I just open a terminal, type the first 2 statements. Open a second terminal and the other. That all works.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to run them on separate terminals programmatically you can use a terminal multiplexer such as GNU screen for that.

First you have to start a session:

```
$ screen -S demo
```

Then open all the terminals you need inside it with Ctrl-a c and configure their environments as needed, and then you can send commands to any screen page (tab) from your script using the "-X stuff" option (to stuff characters into a virtual screen terminal):

```
$ screen -S demo -p <page_number> -X stuff 'ls -l
'
```

Note that you also have to send the newline character to really enter the command.

Answer (score 1):

I try add main enviornment path  to bash and I success run roscore in another terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ROS opstarten
PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin

gnome-terminal --tab -e /opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the statements and use a statement separator between them.

```
gnome-terminal -e 'cd ~/Projects/catkin_ws; source devel/setup.bash; /usr/bin/python /home/user/Projects/catkin_ws/src/drone7_project/src/drone_program.py'
```

or alternatively with newline as statement separator

```
gnome-terminal -e 'cd ~/Projects/catkin_ws
    source devel/setup.bash
    /usr/bin/python /home/user/Projects/catkin_ws/src/drone7_project/src/drone_program.py'
```

However, running these commands in a separate terminal seems rather misdirected. Why don't you run them as regular background jobs in your  current terminal with output to a file?